# Handle 'this' in event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function Foo(map){
    this.map = map;
}  
Foo.prototype = {
    onclick: function(e){
        this.bar(e.point);
    },  
    bar: function(point){
        // do something with point
    },  
    start: function(){
        this.map.addEvent("click", this.onclick);
    },
    stop: function(){
        this.map.removeEvent("click", this.onclick);
    }
};
```

but in `onclick`, `this` is bind to `map`. I'd like it to be bind to `Foo`'s instance.
notice that I can't use an anonymous function as `addEvent`'s second parameter because I need to remove the listener later.

Answer (score 2):

In `start()`, create a closure which references the outer object through a local alias:

```
start: function(){
    var self = this;
    this._handlerFunc = function(){ self.onclick.apply(self, arguments); };
    this.map.addEvent("click", this.handlerFunc);
},
stop: function(){
    this.map.removeEvent("click", this._handlerFunc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the result you want. By creating the object inside the anonymous function you can get a reference to it.

```
Foo.prototype = (function() {
    var f = { }
    f.onclick = function(e){
        f.bar(e.point);
    };
    f.bar = function(point){
        // do something with point
    };  
    f.start = function(){
        this.map.addEvent("click", f.onclick);
    };
    f.stop = function(){
        this.map.removeEvent("click", f.onclick);
    };
    return f;
})();
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/Ypgh5/ (Ignore the contents of the alert, important thing is that it got there!)

Comment: is `this` in `start` still reference to the instance of `Foo`?

Comment: @wong2 Yes, it appears to be - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/Ypgh5/1/ Click works correctly on both divs

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you call event handler. For example (if you are using jQuery):

```
$("foo").click((function () {
    var fooObject = new Foo;
    return function (evt) {
        fooObject.onclick.call(fooObject, evt);
    };
}()));
```

Answer (score 0):

this answer is similar to Richard D's one, but since we want the prototype to return a new object, we could initialize it as one :

```
Foo.prototype = new function() {
    var self = this;
    this.onclick = function(e){
        this.bar(e.point);
    };
    this.bar = function(point){
        // do something with point
    };  
    this.start: function(){
        this.map.addEvent("click", this.onclick);
    };
    this.stop: function(){
        this.map.removeEvent("click", this.onclick);
    };
    // can use the "self" reference in a callback
    this.someEvent = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(self);// can't use this here    
    },100);
};
```